# Google One-Tap Sign-In (YOLO) + Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I noticed Google has re-opened [Google One-Tap Sign-in and Auto-Signup](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web) after having paused it due to a security issue.

I've been trying to understand how to make it work with Firebase Auth, does anyone have any ideas? Even a high-level view of how it should work would be great.

So far, I've managed to create this:

https://google-one-tap.brunocrosier.now.sh

What this does so far:

1. Shows the One-Tap prompt
2. Allows you to click "Continue as {name}"
3. Makes a post request to /api/google and verifies the ID token [as
   per these instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/verify-google-id-token)
4. Outputs the data in JSON format

My question is, how can I then make this work with Firebase Auth ? Can I create a Google user in Firebase with the data that is output in #4 ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

One Tap Google Sign in (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web)

****response**** comes to your function directly via callback from the [One Tap script](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/handle-credential-responses-js-functions).

Firebase 8

```
let credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.credential);

firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(result) {
  let user = result.user
  console.log(user)
});
```

Firebase 9

```
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth"
    
const yourAuth = getAuth(yourApp)
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.credential)
signInWithCredential(yourAuth, credential).then(function (result) {
  const user = result.user
  console.log(user)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Slight variation that in Firebase version 9 you import the GoogleAuthProvider object and the signInWithCredential method from the auth package. After that it works perfectly with google one tap.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something / doing something stupid, but `response` don't have a `credential` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I saw you open sourced your code at: https://github.com/brunocrosier/google-one-tap. Looks like this problem is fixed by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it's hidden in the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/pwa#sign_in_users_across_devices.
TLDR *add the `GOOGLE_YOLO` credentialHelper*

```
var uiConfig = {
  signInSuccessUrl: 'url-to-redirect-to-on-success',
  authMethod: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  signInOptions: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  // Enable one-tap sign-in.
  credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.GOOGLE_YOLO
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually that doesn't work, as FirebaseUI doesn't support YOLO anymore (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/699)

However I did manage to fix this with some (again, hidden) documentation :)

Comment: Typical Google... You should post your workaround thou in case it's useful to anyone else